# Função Copiar e Colar

Tags: java, android

Queria copiar e colar uma string em uma ListView, a função que estou usando tá apenas copiando 
segue a função:

```
// Função Copiar
    private void copiarTarefa(Context context, String text) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            clipboard.setText(text);
        } else {
            android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Texto copiado: ", text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, "Texto copiado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

quando eu chamo a função assim:

```
 // Copiar Nota
            listaTarefas.setLongClickable(true);
            listaTarefas.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    copiarTarefa(getApplicationContext(), textoTarefa.getText().toString());
                    return true;

                }
            });
```

Ele apenas copia e não cola, só faz literalmente copiar.. 
onde está o erro, pois não estou conseguindo recuperar a nota para poder colar

Comment: Vai copiar de onde e colar onda?

Comment: No código só vejo "copiar". Onde está o "colar"?

Comment: pois é Ramaral.. queria saber isso

Comment: copiar e colar para área de trabalho, tas entendendo ?

Comment: Queria saber como eu posso por a função de colar